# Laravel | ask password for certain actions

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I have a form in my Laravel project. And when a user tries to submit this form I want to show a dialog asking their password(for additional security).
i.e I want the logged in user to enter his/her password when he/she wants to do some critical actions and verify that password.

I can figure out the front-end part of this but I don't know how to implement the controller logic for the same.

From documentation I found `Auth::check()` but it only checks if the current user is logged in or not.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask logged in user for a password and then check it manually with `check()` method, for example:

```
if (Hash::check(request('password'), auth()->user()->password))
```

The first argument is a password entered by a user. The second argument is hashed password from DB.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually planning to implement this on one of my websites. Lately, I have been going thought the planning and this is what I came through with:

1. When user comes to the app, he/she logs in
2. He/she adds some of the item to cart. The user has been already auth-ed, so this is not issue.
3. When he/she tries to checkout, check for existence of very specific session item (e.g. `REAUTH_SUCCESS`) and if such existed, proceed. Otherwise, go back and print login form with password field alone. After this, it is just matter of doing what @Alexey and @Robert suggested in their answers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can use a standard Laravel validator rule to check that the form field value supplied matches the current user's password.  For example if the name of the password field in your UI is `password` then you would use:

```
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'password' => 'current_password'
    ]);
```

For more information about validation and the current password rule see the  Laravel docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-current-password